# Write a text file to an USB Storage. Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I want to write a text file to an USB Storage.
Here is what I am trying to do.

```
var fileSystemObj = new FileSystem();  
var usbPath = '$USB_DIR/sda1/';  
var fileObj = fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(usbPath + "log.txt", 'w');  
var log = "USB is successfully accessed.  \n";  
fileObj.writeAll(log);  
fileSystemObj.closeCommonFile(fileObj);
```

I am using the SDK 5.1 and trying this on live TV.
Please let me know where I am getting it wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I got the reply from Samsung support regarding this question and wanted to share their response here:

Unfortunately we don't have a API to write content directly to USB.
But this can be handled using 'copy()' API to copy the content from internal memory to USB( i.e. write the content in memory and then copy it to USB).
Please refer following link for details on 'copy()'  API
http://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/ref50002/file_api_Copy.html